# AngularJS directive leak

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I have a directrive that compiles the following html:

```
<div asi-template class="{{asimon.isTable(_a.path+'.'+key) }}">
```

asimon.isTable is a vanilla javascript function, my question is, does calling a function like that may prevent the GC from collecting it even after the view has been destroyed?

I have no clue of what is making my directive leak.

BTW
This is my directive:

```
module.directive('asiTemplate',
function($compile) {
  return {

    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        var wachingGroup=scope.$watchGroup(
            [
                function(scope){ return scope.$eval(attr.asiPath); },
                function(scope){ return scope.$eval(attr.asiObject); },
                function(scope){ return attr.asiClass; }
            ],
            function(value){
                var scope_id = asi.path.get('scope_id.value', element[0].attributes);
                console.log({scope_id:scope_id, scope:asi.scope[scope_id], attr:element[0].attributes});
                if(asi.scope[scope_id] !== undefined) destroyscope(scope_id);

                asi.template.load(element, attr, scope);
            }
        );
        scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
            wachingGroup();//desregistra el watchgroup  
            element.remove();

        });
    }
}
});
```

Comment: How did you know that it is leaking? Do you have any benchmarks?

Comment: Yes, I made a performance monitor with chrome and got this https://imgur.com/a/D1Mdj just by repeating the same action